# How to disable the darkening of unfocused windows in Fedora 20? (Gnome3)

Tags: gnome3, fedora-20

When I'm using a window, the other ones become darker.

The problem is I find it annoying because sometimes I need to keep open a manual in Gedit while I type commands in the terminal. The darkening on Gedit makes it harder to read.

I couldn't find how to customize this. I only found a gnome extension to make unfocused windows even darker.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is any built-in configuration on Fedora for this but you can try using the [`Windows Transparent`](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/684/transparent-windows/) extension.

First, remove the extension you mentioned to *make the windows become darker*. After install the `Windows Transparent` extension.

> Allows setting custom opacity globaly and per window basis. You can assign different opacity to **active** and **inactive** windows. Also there is a simple mode if all you need are transparent terminals.

Note: *[Will not work on anything below 3.10](https://github.com/saysilence/transparentwindows)*

Good luck.

Comment: I didn't install any extensions to make the unfocused windows darker, that happens by default and I need to disable it.